# An SQL query that uses values from two columns in a Between Operator and adds these two columns as a class for the result

Tags: sql

In one table, I have a column that contains a letter and another that contains a letter of a later alphabetical order. Like 'A' for the former and 'R' for the latter for example. I want to use these two columns in a Between operator to search for words in another table that starts a letter from the first column and ends with a letter from the second. So in my example, 'Air' would fit this requirement. The problem is I also need to add these two columns to results, so that for my example, the query would return 'Air' with 'A' and 'R' from the other table as two columns in my results. Sorry I can't be more explicit as the data is sensitive.

Comment: Which DMBS are you using? You will need to inject a wildcard character into your first column then use it in a `LIKE` operator, e.g. stuff `%` into `AR` to get `A%R`, then you can use `WHERE ColFromAnotherTable LIKE 'A%R'`, but how exactly you do this will likely depend on the particular DMBS you are using.

Comment: Please illustrate current data and desired results with data. Human language tends to be less precise than numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you have described here is one way to get the output.

```
create table t(id int, start_letter varchar(1), end_letter varchar(1));
create table search_data(words varchar(50))
insert into t values(1,'A','R')

begin
insert into search_data values('Air');
insert into search_data values('Amour');
insert into search_data values('Arogant');
end;
```

---

```
select *
  from search_data a
  join t b
    on lower(substring(a.words,1,1))=lower(b.start_letter)
   and lower(substring(reverse(a.words),1,1))=lower(b.end_letter)


+-------+----+--------------+------------+
| words | id | start_letter | end_letter |
+-------+----+--------------+------------+
| Air   |  1 | A            | R          |
| Amour |  1 | A            | R          |
+-------+----+--------------+------------+

db fiddle link
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=82cf80f4b76cb740ae56db8f236bfd46
```